# How To Get ANSI Escape Sequences Working in Erlang Werl?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Erlang R17.0 x64 on Windows 7 x64.

When I type `clear` in a werl window, I see the ANSI escape sequence displayed.  I also tried `clear()`--same result.  From my digging around it looks like werl should be able to handle ANSI escape sequences.  Is there something I need to do to get this working?

Comment: I'm using the R17 x64 also on Windows 7 x64 but I'm not sure what you meant for: _I see the ANSI escape sequence displayed_.

Comment: @Machina http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code